# How to use regex to look for occurence of certain numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regex to look for a certain occurrence of numbers, then add more numbers to it if those numbers are entered?

```
//Pseudocode
regex = 123
input = 1234567
if input[3] = regex
{
  input + 07
}  
output = 07123467
```

Comment: You want `07 + input` otherwise your code would produce `123456707`.

Comment: Why regex? You can use `indexOf`

Comment: Is my answer of any use to you?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I suggest you start off with some basic, such as what strings are and how to represent them, how to write regexps, how to test against them, and how to declare variables.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? For example, input[3] isn't really valid javascript, what were you trying to convey there? Did you want the 3rd index of the string? Let us know if you have questions. The comments here are a good place to get feedback on how to make the question better so people will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var searchSequence = 123;
var fullSequence = 9999991234567;

var searchString = searchSequence.toString();
var fullString = fullSequence.toString();

var searchIndex;
if ((searchIndex = fullString.indexOf(searchString)) != -1) {
    fullString = fullString.substring(0, searchIndex) + '07' + fullString.substring(searchIndex);
    fullSequence = Number(fullString);
    alert(fullSequence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) a sequence of numbers with another sequence. Depending on the context, you may need to search and splice the string, but there's a good chance you can simply:

```
'123456'.replace('123', '07$&')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using the `test` method for Regex

If you want to use regex to determine whether the characters 123 are present in your input, you can use the [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method. It returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the input matches the regex.

```
var regex = /123/;
var input = 1234567;
var output = input;

if (regex.test(input)) {  //=> true
  output = '07' + input;  //=> '071234567'
}
```

### Exact Match

It's important to note that the regex `/123/` will only match inputs with that **exact** sequence of numbers. For example:

```
var regex = /123/;
regex.test(8);            //=> false
regex.test(12);           //=> false
regex.test(312);          //=> false
regex.test(7123);         //=> true
regex.test('0123');       //=> true
```

### Partial Match

If you wanted to match **any** number in that set, simply create a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by adding square brackets.

```
var regex = /[123]/;
regex.test(8);            //=> false
regex.test(12);           //=> true
regex.test(312);          //=> true
regex.test(7123);         //=> true
regex.test('0123');       //=> true
```

You can play around more using the popular javascript regex sandbox [Scriptular](http://scriptular.com/). I highly recommend it, it includes a cheat sheet for regex syntax which is very helpful.